# Adding a hyperlink freezes Outlook 2016 (Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2016)

Tags: networking, windows-10, freeze, microsoft-outlook-2016, hyperlink

When trying to create a hyperlink in a new email, the corresponding form pops up but then freezes Outlook on Windows 10 for several minutes. Eventually it continues normally. I've found a number of similar problems described on the internet but none of the solutions really seem to apply. I have reinstalled my profile recently and when testing it right after reinstallation, creating hyperlinks worked fine. However, when I really needed it one hour later, it stopped working again.

I read somewhere that this may be related to unresolved network links and I sort of have a hunch this might also be my problem, but how do I search my computer for such broken links? More generally, what could cause my temporary freezes?

Comment: Have you checked in the Event Viewer when the freezing issue occurred? Besides, considering that it worked fine right after reinstallation, it is suggested to try performing a Windows clean boot to narrow down if the problem is related to any software conflicts.

Comment: @Yuki Sun, thanks for the tip. I've rebooted, went straight into Outlook, composed a new email, and went directly into creating a link, but Outlook still freezes for three or four minutes. I watched the event viewer. Initially I saw error and warning counts go up, but as I was trying to dig deeper regarding the event ID, I kept redoing the same thing only to find out that in one attempt, trying to create a hyperlink didn't trigger any event at all. So in summary, the event viewer didn't reveal anything either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the root cause. There was a link to a non-existing disk in my Documents folder. After removing that, Outlook started behaving normally again. I hope this helps others who may run into the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the number of shortcuts you have in your default folder (it's My Documents for me). If you have a lot of shortcuts in that folder, Outlook tries to reach/resolve each link before letting you add anything.

If you do have tons of shortcuts in that folder, move them to a folder called "Shortcuts" or something.